# Why this sql statement alway cause '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax'?

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO 'test' ('name', 'remark') VALUES ('133', '4545')
```

Tabke 'test' is existing and name id varchar(14), remark is varchar(140).
It's always cause error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test' ('name', 'remark') VALUES ('133', '4545')' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Table and column names should be wrapped with backticks, not single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `remark`) VALUES ('133', '4545')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
INSERT INTO 'test' ('name', 'remark') VALUES ('133', '4545')
```

To

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `remark`) VALUES ('133', '4545')
```

Remove single quote with backtick

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `remark`) VALUES ('133', '4545')
```